# What's the smallest 3-blade propeller for this motor?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, vtol, quadcopter

I've got a [15470 brushless 35kw motor](http://freerchobby.cc/e_productshow/?17-620usdpcs-17.html) from China
How do I find the smallest 3-blade propeller I can use for this motor?

Here are it's specs,
**Max Power:** 35KW
**Max Amp:** 400A
**Max RPM:** 8500
**Max Volt:** 120v
**Torque:** 75Nm
**Resistance:** .94

I've looked into eCalc but it's for determining power / thrust, etc and not finding prop size.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Because 120 * 35 our maximum RPM would be 4,200" - Come again? You can't get the maximum RPM by multiplying the voltage by the power.

Comment: Since you're looking for "smallest prop", how much thrust do you need out of it and how much torque can your motor supply at 4200 rpm?

Comment: @DanPichelman I've added more detail to the question, the manufacturer recommends a 36-40 inch 2-blade propeller, so I was wondering how to calculate an equivalent 3-blade propeller (or do I just take off an inch as is the "rule of thumb"?)

Comment: Seems like the **pitch** of the propeller would matter quite a bit here as well.

Comment: I seriously doubt that thing is rated for life safety.  You would need to use it in a jurisdiction that has lax safety regs.

Answer (score 2):

You need the largest prop that keeps the tip speed below about .9 Mach, roughly 1000 ft/sec, so you want the largest propeller than can operate at that RPM at .9 mach.  [Here's](https://www.warpdriveprops.com/propspd2.html) a tip speed calculator for larger propellers that should suffice.